# Python opencv Very long Hough lines

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I'm trying to obtain hough lines for pentagon, triangle and square. 
Here is the Edge image obtained from cv2.canny [image]

Environment : Python 2.7, Opencv 2.4.11

```
img = cv2.imread("shapes.png")
grayimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cannygrayimgBlur = cv2.Canny(grayimg, 50, 150)  
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
lines =cv2.HoughLinesP(cannygrayimgBlur,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But the result is super strange. Only the complete edges of the square are drawn.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change the threshold (in HoughLinesP, it is 100 in your case) to something lower? or maybe minLineLength also to something smaller?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that (20,30,40), works better, but the edges are still not fully connected.